# What are good ways of dealing with client side timeouts when connecting to a remote service since the outcome of the request becomes unknown?

Tags: database, web-services, transactions, client

To clarify, are there any good ways of dealing with a request to a remote service that times out on a client leaving the outcome of the request in doubt?

Assume the following setup:

```
thick client <--> web service <--> database
```

Assume the following is the typical process for saving data:

1. the thick client sends a put request to the web service
2. the web service commits the data to the database
3. the web service returns success to the thick client

I don't know how to handle a situation where a client side timeout occurs between steps 2 and 3.  In such a case, the person sitting in front of the thick client is going to think their request failed, but it was actually successful.

Is there a way of mitigating such a situation that doesn't involve trying to explain to the person using the thick client that the state of the request is in doubt?  I don't think I could write an error message that would do the job.

The next request is also a problem.  If the original request was to create new data, the subsequent request may create duplicate data.  If the original request was to update existing data and the server is using an optimistic locking strategy, the subsequent request will cause another error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to enable the client to check at a later time (maybe 10s or a minute) if the operation in fact did succeed. You would need to enhance your webservice to have such an API.

Alternatively, you could set the client timeout really high, but after one minute you show the user the timeout message. If at a later point the webservice call unexpectedly succeeds, you can interrupt the user with a messagebox telling him that the operation completed.